# Django Rest Framework Model Serializer Aditional Keyword Argument not recognized

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following DRF serializer:

```
class ServiceStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ServiceStatus
        fields = ('id', 'service', 'status', 'timestamp', 'comment')
        extra_kwargs = {'content_object': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        result = super().create(validated_data)
        
        return result
```

I am trying to implement additional keyword arguments to `ModelSerializer`s as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), but serializer's `create()` method doesn't receive the extra parameter in `validated_data`, as you can see in this debug watch expression:

[image]

You can see that `validated_data` parameter only contains three keys and misses key `content_object`, even when it was sent from Postam POST request:

[image]

I can't find out what I am missing.

Comment: I think you just have to add your content_object to the fields list , add extra_kwargs = {'content_object': {'write_only': True}} if you want it to be readonly.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the `extra_kwargs` is used to declare extra kwargs to fields that were declared directly on the `fields` - which isn't the case for you. I'd suggest you doing something like this:

```
class ServiceStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_object = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.ServiceStatus
        fields = ('id', 'service', 'status', 'timestamp', 'comment',
                  'content_object',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        result = super().create(validated_data)
        
        return result
```